# How can I disable button and change the button text on this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know very well jquery/javascript and I am having problems with the code below.

After the form validation steps, the button is disabled but the form is not submited. Where is wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $('.form_error').hide();
    $("#submit_button").click(function() {

    var tempo_show = 400
    $('.form_error').hide();

    var card_name = $("input#card_name").val();
    if (card_name == "") {
    $("span#validation_card_name").fadeIn(tempo_show);
    //alert("Informe o Nome do titula do cartão");
    $("input#card_name").focus();
    return false;
    }

    var owner_birthdate = $("input#owner_birthdate").val();
    if (owner_birthdate.length < 8) {
    $("span#validation_owner_birthdate").fadeIn(tempo_show);
    //alert("Informe o Nome do titula do cartão");
    $("input#owner_birthdate").focus();
    return false;
    }

    // here is where I can't make work
    $(this).html('Processando...');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

    });
  });
```

Comment: try returning true at end of submit click handler, or calling .submit() on the form element.

Comment: I think this $("input#card_name").val(); should be this $("#card_name").val();. The reason is you don't need to specify the element type when you want to get them by ID. Make similar changes to the rest of the code as well.

Comment: You mean `return true;` after `$(this).attr('disabled', true);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this `$("input#card_name").val();` should be this `$("#card_name").val();`. The reason is you don't need to specify the element type when you want to get them by ID. Make similar changes to the rest of the code as well. Try adding `$("#YOURFORMID").submit()` at the end.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.form_error').hide();
    $("#submit_button").click(function() {

    var tempo_show = 400
    $('.form_error').hide();

    var card_name = $("#card_name").val();
    if (card_name == "") {
    $("#validation_card_name").fadeIn(tempo_show);
    //alert("Informe o Nome do titula do cartão");
    $("#card_name").focus();
    return false;
    }

    var owner_birthdate = $("#owner_birthdate").val();
    if (owner_birthdate.length < 8) {
    $("#validation_owner_birthdate").fadeIn(tempo_show);
    //alert("Informe o Nome do titula do cartão");
    $("#owner_birthdate").focus();
    return false;
    }

    // here is where I can't make work
    $(this).html('Processando...');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        $("#YOURFORMID").submit();

    });
  });
```